# Netbeans platforme : How can I hide or remove the number displayed in front of the name?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

When ran, the netbeans platform application has [the name of the projet]+[A sequence number] as name for the window. Is there a way, I can remove the number and keep the project name ?

I reckon that It's a simple question, but I can't seem to find how.

Comment: Please provide more information. Screenshots maybe? It is not clear, what you mean.

Comment: @padde I would if I could. 9 points are not enough.
In the first image of the tutorial in the link bellow. Look at the name of the window.
https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use branding. Right click on your application module and choose *Branding..*. There you go to *Resource Bundles* and scroll down to `org/netbeans/core/startup/Bundle.properties`. There should be a property inside named `currentVersion`, set to your application title (which you can choose in the *Basic* tab) and an appended `{0}`. This is replaced with the current date.

Remove that `{0}` and you should have what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks padde, actually when I did as you said, the numbers didn't disapear, so I did the same for CTL_MainWindow_Title and CTL_MainWindow_Title_No_Project, in org/netbeans/core/windows/view/ui/Bundles.properties.